# Create UIImageView in UIImageView with full fit shape in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell

I have UIImageView which used [UIImageView-Letters](https://github.com/bachonk/UIImageView-Letters) lib.
I want to create new UIImageView, which place in the top of previous one with completely fit it's shape and size.

Creating first view:

```
[cell.photo setImageWithString:@"N A"
                         color:[UIColor redColor]
                      circular:YES];
```

Creating second view:

```
- (UIImageView *)createRecordAnimationViewFrom:(UIImageView *)imageView {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(imageView.bounds.origin.x,
                             imageView.bounds.origin.y,
                             imageView.bounds.size.width,
                             imageView.bounds.size.height);
    UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect
                                                          cornerRadius:imageView.bounds.size.width / 2];

    UIImageView *progressView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    progressView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    progressView.alpha = 0.5;
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

    maskLayer.frame = progressView.frame;
    maskLayer.path = [bezierPath CGPath];
    progressView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    progressView.tag = 101;

    return progressView;
}
```

Append one to other:

```
[cell.photo addSubview:[self createRecordAnimationViewFrom:cell.photo]];`
```

called from

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {`
```

Already tried works with

```
cell.photo.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
cell.photo.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

No help.

My problem is second view do not fit the size of first (it's not autoresizing via auto layout at all), as you can find on image.

What I'm missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed via moving `(UIImageView *)createRecordAnimationViewFrom:(UIImageView *)imageView` into `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {})` block.